# My While loop is not working, why?

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

I have a question in relationship to loops in php. I am trying play actions with the elements of my array, always with the last one. To do this I need:

1- To know my array is not empty.

2- To pickup the last item name of my array. This is because I need it to execute the Step0.php script.

3- To delete the last item of my array.

I want to repeat this action until the value of my array is zero and go out to this loop.

I tried this but I had not lucky. :-(

Any idea?

```
$array2;
$array1;
$diffe_array = array_diff($array2, $array1);

//CREATE THE CONDICTION
$diffe=count($diffe_array);
do {
     $lastone=end($diffe_array);
     require('./Step0.php');
     $extract=array_pop($diffe_array); 
     $diffe=count($diffe_array);
     print_r($diffe_array);
} while ($diffe > 0);

echo 'JUST YOU HAVE 0 ITEMS IN YOUR ARRAY!!!!';
```

To complete my question I think is necessary to have clear (with this example):

**Step1**.- I have $array2 like this:

array2 ( [0] => 00004.csv [1] => 00007.csv [2] => 00005.csv [3] => 00003.csv [4] => 00002.csv [5] => 00001.csv [6] => 00006.csv [7] => 00000.csv )

**Step2**.- I have &array1 like this:

array1 ( [0] => 00004.csv [1] => 00003.csv [2] => 00002.csv [3] => 00001.csv [4] => 00000.csv )

**Step3**.- I calculate diffe_array with array_diff($array2,$array1):

diffe_array ( [1] => 00007.csv [2] => 00005.csv [6] => 00006.csv )

**Step4**.- I need create a loop to extract each item from my diffe_array and use it in my other script Step0.php (this script open the file with the same name of my last item in my diffe_array and share its info into a database). I need to do this until my diffe_array is empty, so it goes out form the loop.

By the way, the content of Step0.php is:

```
<?php

function Conection() 
{
       if (!($link=pg_connect("host=xxxxx port=xxxx dbname=xxxxx user=xxxxx password=xxxxx")))  { 
           echo "Error connecting to the database.";
           exit();
       }
       return $link;
}
require_once('./process.php');//This is the before file
$rute="/rute/to/my/file/";
$end= $rute.$lastone;
$row = 0;
$handle = fopen($end, "r"); 
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
    $num = count($data); 
    $row++;
    echo '<b><br/><br/>';
    $request = "insert into table(column1,column2,column3,column4) values("; 
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { 
        if ($c==($num-1))
              $request = $request."'".$data[$c] . "'";
        else
              $request = $request."'".$data[$c] . "',";
    }

    $request = $request.");"; 
    echo $request."<br>";  

     $union=Conection();
     $result=pg_query($union, $request); 
     pg_close($union);
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: What is in `$array1` and `$array2`

Comment: Why not simply array_reverse your $diffe_array; then foreach($diffe_array as $extract)?

Comment: Good option!!

I will try it!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all - following your code - `$array1` and `$array2` have no values, so I suppose that `array_diff()` function will return you an error.

Second, with your code, you'll going to include `Step0.php` at every loop. This isn't a good approach.

Last point: why do you use `count()` every time, if you know the count before you enter loop and pop only one element? Isn't better to decrement `$diffe` variable?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer.

Sorry for the poor accuracy of my explanation.

1.-We assume that $array1 and $array2 is not empty. So $diffe_array is not empty too.

2.- I don´t know other way to execute my second script.

3.- I use count like a way to control the operations (then I'll write echo)

Thanks.

Comment: @user2343971: you have to write a "good" example for have a "good" answer. So, please update that code with your REAL code: if above is real code, you can't assume that "arrays are not empty" :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your core, initializing $diffe_array to array(1, 2, 3), and the loop processed 3 times, so probably there's something wrong with your initial data ($array1, $array2). Also, like DonCallisto mentioned, there are easier ways to iterate over array backwards - for instance, by using for loop accordingly, like:

```
for ($i = count($diffe_array)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
    echo $diffe_array[$i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks leafnode!!

My arrays are:

Array2 ( [0] => 00004.csv [1] => 00007.csv [2] => 00005.csv [3] => 00003.csv [4] => 00002.csv [5] => 00001.csv [6] => 00006.csv [7] => 00000.csv )
 
Array1 ( [0] => 00004.csv [1] => 00003.csv [2] => 00002.csv [3] => 00001.csv [4] => 00000.csv )

Diffe_array ( [1] => 00007.csv [2] => 00005.csv [6] => 00006.csv )

And my count(diffe_array) is 3.

With this data my do-while loop processed 1 times only.

Comment: Check if step0.php is not modifying $diffe_array at any point - e.g. you could do print_r($diffe_array) at the end of the loop.

Comment: Then of several tests I can say my while loop is working but the problem is in step0.php, but I don´t know exactly where.
When go into to the while it is not execute the step0.php file.

I edited the original question with the code o stept0.php

Answer (score 0):

use while loop like this

```
 while ($diffe > 0) {
         $lastone=end($diffe_array);
         require('./Step0.php');
         $extract=array_pop($diffe_array); 
         $diffe=count($diffe_array);
         print_r($diffe_array);
    }
```

Comment: Chirag ode, I tried the "classic" while and the result is the same. :(
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Missing: $array2 =array();

$array2 and $array1 are not array.

**Remember that**: 
The condition is tested at the end of the block instead of the beginning, so the block will be executed at least once. If the condition is true, we jump back to the beginning of the block and execute it again. A do..while loop is basically a reversed while loop. A while loop says "Loop while the condition is true, and execute this block of code", a do..while loop says "Execute this block of code, and loop while the condition is true".

So, in your do{} block require is missing... and lastly your have got a fatal error from require('./Step0.php');

Thanks